# Which sparse matrix is the most efficient for indexing and assigning values in python?

Tags: numpy, scipy

I want to create sparse matrix `sB` from sparse matrix `sA`:

```
# create the example data
A = np.array([ [0, 2], [3, 0] ])
IdxP = np.array([9,100])
IdxN = np.array([50,30])
n, p = np.where(A)
sA = sparse.csr_matrix(A) 

sB =sparse.lil_matrix((200,200))
sB[IdxP[p], IdxN[n]] = sA[p, n]
```

In the example, I use `lil_matrix` for `sB` and `csr_matrix` for `sA` for the indexing and assignment. Is there a better combination to make it faster?

Comment: Usually it's not indexing and assignment that you care about as much as the expensive operations you plan on doing down the line: multiplication, inversion, etc.

Comment: Assuming *sA* is contructed matching the order of *IdxP, IdxN*, `sparse.coo_matrix((sA.data, (IdxP, IdxN)), (200,200))` uses the available data directly and is ~3.5x faster for the minimal example, but the result is different. It doesn't reorder *IdxP, IdxN* by the non-zero indices of *A*, or swap row and column indices when *sA* is indexed. Please provide an explanation for these additional steps to be considered in a solution.

Comment: @MadPhysicist - Most likely you are right and this is a negligible micro-optimization, but information on this topic in the documentation is sparse: *To construct a matrix efficiently, use either dok_matrix or lil_matrix. [...]. As illustrated below, the COO format may also be used to efficiently construct matrices*. I think after having clarified the question, it might be worth benchmarking different solutions.

Comment: @MichaelSzczesny To get the same result, it should be `sparse.coo_matrix((sA.data, (IdxP[p], IdxN[n])), (200,200))`. Did I answer your question?